# E Charts - Enable tooltip for X axis label

Tags: tooltip, echarts

I need to enable tooltip while **hovering over x-Axis** labels in **E-Charts**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
}
```